# Adding a stored procedure in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I want to add a stored procedure that will return a result set with after passing 6 parameters in, in Sqlite. How can I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

SQLite does not have stored procedures.

As an embedded database, SQLite has no client/server communication overhead, and is designed to be used together with a 'real' programming language.
Write the procedure in that language.

Comment: Nonetheless, it could be a feature as many others!